# Analysis of pull requests

Tags: build, azure-devops, analytics, pull-request

I am using VSTS, I would like to do analysis of Pull requests (PR) for the following

1. How many of them are approved/approved with suggestions/rejected, Abandon.
2. How many PR got review comments, how many of them do not have any review comments
3. Which reviewer gave most of the comments, which developer got most of the review comments etc.

Is there any existing tool or feature of VSTS to achieve this?

Atul

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the easiest way to do this, would be to use SonarCloud, see here: https://sonarcloud.io/about/sq/branch-analysis-and-pr-decoration

Other than that, I think you would need to make use of the REST Api's in TFS/VSTS/Azure Devops for this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0